# SIZE OF THE KERNEL IMAGES

Tags: linux-kernel

Which command should i use to know the size of the kernel images in linux?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the location of your kernel image which will be generally in /boot directory on your kernel. Then run the command du -hs  or du -s .